# c# checkedlistbox setitemcheckstate works but will not display checkedindices

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, checkedlistbox

I am using VS2012 to update and old project that was is using .NET 4.  The version of the **CheckedListBox** is reporting version 4.0.0.  I have search and read and have everything working but having the control display the **CheckedIndicies**.  I can programmatically affect the items I want in the form load event.  **Before** the load event finishes I can confirm that **CheckedIndicies** are correct.

```
private void InterviewPresentation_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        short code = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < clb_conditions.Items.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            code = ((ConditionListItem)clb_conditions.Items[i]).Code;
            if (code == 1 | code == 20)
            {
                clb_conditions.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Checked);
            }
        }
        clb_conditions.Refresh();
    }
```

I even through in the **clb_conditions.Refresh()** to see if the control needed to **Invalidate** and Refresh to display the two items that should be checked according to  **CheckedIndices**.

I have been up and down the forums and am ready to pull my hair out.

Comment: `I am using VS2012 to update and old project...` - Nice opportunity to move from decade-old winforms into the modern, easier, more scalable, more performant, not hack-prone world of XAML.

Comment: Found the answer guys but I do not like it.  It was code in clb_conditions_VisibleChanged event.  I had set a break point to stop at the end of the Load event and was pretty sure that I was using F11 to set what came next.  Between this discovery I had rebooted for something else and was able to get F11 to step into after a co-worker identified what was happening.  Has anyone else experience F11 not stepping into some of these events.  This is not the first time I have noticed it.